# What can be done about the "const *iption" spam?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, moderation, const-iption-trolling

Is there anything that can be done about the const *iption troll? Maybe an automated filter that rejects all questions with the string "const *ipt"? All but one of the questions I've seen used that string either on its own "const ipt" or in "*const * iption". The other used the supposed definition of const *iption without using the word itself.

Comment: Maybe it's a typo for **[conscription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscription)**?

Comment: @Rick no, they defined it as contacting a government official, specifically the POTUS, with a demand that said official not take a salary. It was supposedly originally done to protest conscription during the Vietnam War, but there's no evidence that the concept existed prior to the questions.

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? I downvoted @Someone ‘s actual question cause it’s feeding the troll. Especially what seems now its own tag — ridiculous. But this is a legitimate question. He/she/they kept coming back and not only on two occasions merely with the intent of instilling a false concept to have for the GOP something to chew on. I hope the mods will delete the tag reading “constiption”.

Comment: @kisspuska yeah, the tag wasn't a good idea, thanks for fixing it. This question was asked before the trolling was quite the persistent issue it is now.

Answer (score 8):

So far as I can see the user in question posted exactly two questions, neither one spam. Arguably they were bad questions, particularly the first, but that is a pretty small troll, even if you concede them to be trolling, which I do not.

A site-wide filter, if possible, would IMO not be justified until there was far more disruption than two bad questions. I don't think that is even justification to suspend a user. So I would say nothing unusual should be done.

Comment: I've seen at least five. "Is constiption a crime" twice, "is constiption illegal", "is it legal to send a letter to the President demanding that he refuse to take a salary" (not sure about the wording of that one, but it's close), and "is it legal to constipt the President." They seem to have used multiple accounts with the same display name, "Worried".

Comment: Evan at five instances, I don't see a case for any extraordinary action. There are already mod tools for dealing  with such cases.

Comment: How about OP's recent question asking if constiption causes acne on Medical Sciences.SE? That proves it's 100% trolling.

Comment: @CareyGregory Who are you referring to as “OP”? Here “OP” is user “Someone”. Are you saying that user “Someone” posted that on Medical Sciences.SE? Please respond.

Comment: This isn’t the first question of user Someone on the topic, here is another: https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1572/should-i-stop-answering-the-constiption-questions?cb=1

Comment: I constipt this post.

Answer (score 4):

I propose that we create a question and answer on the main site, mark the answer community wiki, and lock the question.

- The question: Is const iption a recognized legal concept?
- The answer: no (potentially linking to some of dictionary research done in a few meta answers here).

Then, we can just close any question relating to const iption as a duplicate of that. Or, maybe this is too much effort for something that'll just pass and we should just continue ignoring. I'll take upvotes as support of creating the question; downvotes as against.

Comment: The problem with doing that is that it creates a substantial Google result for a word that is, as best we can tell, being made up.

Comment: @feetwet how does a Google result for a page discrediting something legitimize the topic? Does a Web site saying the earth is round legitimize the flat-earth conspiracy theory?

Comment: Also at least DDG already knows about constiption: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Alaw.stackexchange.com+%22constiption%22&t=fpas&ia=web

Comment: @Someone See, for example, [this comment](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1593/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-about-constiption#comment3730_1593).  If it appears on Stack Exchange as an open Q&A then others might not so easily conclude that it "is not a thing."

Comment: @feetwet it already appears on stack exchange, and DDG still shows a lot of them.

Comment: @Someone try the links, most of them go into 404-land unless you have privileges, or you need to open cached versions.

Comment: @Trish I do have deleted content privileges. Should I delete the question and answer I posted ?

Comment: @Someone I... dunno actually

Comment: @Trish if a mod doesn't delete it or give me a suggestion, I'll delete it if it gets a few downvotes.

Comment: It looks like at least one mod thinks it's a good idea, because it's now locked, preventing me from deleting it.

Answer (score 3):

### Offer them advice

The unregistered user re-appeared and asked about them [here](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1552/why-are-my-constiption-questions-unpopular), give them an answer why they appear spam to you.

Comment: That post was closed and deleted.