# Should I stop answering the const *iption questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, const-iption-trolling

I've been trying to answer the last couple const *iption questions, but my answers to both were downvoted. Should I stop answering them?

Comment: What exactly is constiption? A google search only yields results for constipation, even when I tell google that I spelled it right

Comment: @SomeGuy it's a made up word that someone's trolling about. https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1549/44937

Comment: @SomeGuy they also post things like this acting like they're suing the community: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/84788/notice-of-conditional-constiption

Comment: Gotcha ---------

Comment: Sounds a bit like the story about "quiz".  https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/word-history-of-quiz  Maybe they think they can make "constiption" be a word  :-D

Comment: @A.B. could be, although their apology implies they were just trolling. BTW, it's better to write "const iption" to avoid creating Google results for the word.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes: [DNFTT](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/don%27t_feed_the_troll)

Answer (score 10):

> Should I stop answering the const *iption questions?

Yes. It makes no sense for you to answer questions [you yourself consider spam](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1547/what-can-be-done-about-the-constiption-spam), your [stated reason](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/84788/notice-of-conditional-constiption#comment187462_84788) for voting to close a related question is that "const *iption is not real", and agree that it's [good that the question was deleted](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1566/how-was-this-question-deleted).

Answer (score 1):

It's all about Signal-Noise Ratio.  High S/N attracts participants, low S/N drives them away.

ElitistJerks.com achieved a StackExchange-tier S/N ratio, even though they were **a forum format** about a video game frequented by teenagers. This herculean task was accomplished with with tough rules. One was unforgettable:

## Do not respond to terrible postings.

Vitally, this makes *no judgment whatsoever* about the motivation of the original poster.

It is solely focused on the question of whether adding content will improve overall forum quality.  Of course on EJ this was enforced with the banhammer, but one hopes fear is not your motivator but rather a desire to *retain* what drew you to StackExchange in the first place: **quality**.

Unfortunately it is a human failing that we seek out excellent things, and then forget not to junk them up with our own nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

## After some deliberation: CLOSE AS UNCLEAR/FOCUS!

Closing as unclear or lack of focus does not leave any comment. They seem to strive on them.

## FLAG as SPAM!

6 spam flags auto-delete a question.

### If possible: flag the questions after deletion

...for orbital strikes, nukes and colony drops, so the account can get "nuked"

Comment: Oh, I'll definitely start flagging as spam. I'd been flagging with "Constiption" as a custom flag reason. I wonder if we should stop downvoting the questions? We should probably downvote answers to avoid confusing legitimate askers, but having zero scores on the questions shouldn't be a problem.