# How was this question deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, const-iption-trolling

https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/84484/is-it-legal-to-constipt-biden

This question (the latest iteration of the const *iption spam/trolling) was deleted by Community with only two downvotes and one answer with one downvotes, when the question was under an hour old. Obviously it's good that the question was deleted, but how did the Community bot "know" to delete it?

Comment: community bot does enforce people-bans afaik

Comment: Maybe it was Flagged instead of being VTC.

Comment: I have written up the last chapter in the constiption thing... thank you for updating it when I missed a couple of questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The user was destroyed

That automatically deletes all posts with negative downvotes.

Comment: Maybe they were constipted.